ORACLE ORA-30483: window functions not allowed in subquery
I am doing a work allocation summary report for a flight management system. I need to select the top 5 work roles that have the highest salary. I wanted to use subquery to rank the salary and only select the records with with the first 5 ranking.
Here is my select statement:
SELECT flightType, workRole, rankedSalary.staffId, name, COUNT(workId) AS noOfShift, SUM(payRate) as totalPayRate, AVG(payRate) as avgPayRate, SUM(salary) AS totalSalary, AVG(salary) AS avgSalary
FROM 
    (SELECT staffId, name, 
            RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY flightType ORDER BY SUM(salary) DESC) salaryRank
    FROM staff s
        WHERE RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY flightType ORDER BY SUM(salary) DESC) <= 5
    ) rankedSalary
JOIN workAllocation wa   ON rankedSalary.staffId = wa.staffId
JOIN schedule sch    ON wa.scheduleId = sch.scheduleId
WHERE workStartDate BETWEEN '01/01/2021' AND '01/01/2022'
GROUP BY flightType, rankedSalary.staffId, name, workRole
ORDER BY flightType, salaryRank;

Oracle gives me this error:

ORA-30483: window  functions are not allowed here

I also tried to create the rank in my select statement below, but it still gives me the same error
SELECT flightType, workRole, RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY flightType ORDER BY SUM(salary) DESC) AS salaryRank, 
s.staffId, name, COUNT(workId) AS noOfShift, SUM(payRate) as totalPayRate, AVG(payRate) as avgPayRate, SUM(salary) AS totalSalary, AVG(salary) AS avgSalary
FROM staff s
JOIN workAllocation wa   ON s.staffId = wa.staffId
JOIN schedule sch    ON wa.scheduleId = sch.scheduleId
WHERE workStartDate BETWEEN '01/01/2021' AND '01/01/2022'
AND RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY flightType ORDER BY SUM(salary) DESC) <= 5
GROUP BY flightType, s.staffId, name, workRole
ORDER BY flightType, salaryRank;

I know I can do this by creating a view, but is there any way that I can do it using subquery?

Using a CTE is in such cases easier and better to read than pure subqueries. Build your rating in a CTE and then select from the result using a WHERE clause.

You can't use analytic functions in WHERE clause. In your first code omit the WHERE clause in subquery and add a condition to the outer query WHERE clause to filter to just those 5 rows... ( ... AND salaryRank <= 5 )
